# ADAL 3.1.203031538-alpha: Problems calling AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync() in ASPNET5 and ASPNET5Core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, adal

I am trying to write a library in ASPNET5 Core using VS2015 CTP6 that calls the Azure Service Management REST API.  The code works fine in a .NET45 Console App.

In an ASPNET5Core Console App, the code fails silently on the AcquireTokenAsync call and the program terminates.

In an ASPNET5 Console App, the program won't even build with errors stating I must add a reference to System.Threading.Tasks and System.Runtime.

You can find a repo containing all three projects here:

https://github.com/npnelson/ADALSamples.git  (make sure you read the readme on the repo for more information)

Are these bugs, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET Core support in the current ADAL Alpha is provided only for confidential client flows, that is - code behind of web applications and processes running on the server. Native clients on .NET core are not supported.